# Error in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to make a batch script for killing a process with some process id. I scripted a few cmd commands as:

```
echo " So what is the process id that is blocking tcp.."
set /p prcs_id="Enter the process id of the process you want to terminate :"
pause 
echo I got the process id: %prcs_id%
pause
taskkill /PID %prcs_id% /F
```

But the `taskkill` code gives me the error as such :

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for /PID
```

What might be the possible cause for this- since when I run the command as it is in cmd I get no error...

Comment: Please, don't post images of texts - it is harder to read...

Comment: Post the actual code (all relevant to reproduce) so we may better assist you in fixing it please.

Comment: I recommend turning `echo` on, so that you can see *exactly* the command that is giving you the syntax error.  I think something unexpected is ending up in `%prcs_id%`.  I tried your code, and did not have a problem.

Comment: @abelenky when I turned to get the echo %prcs_id% just after the set /p procs_id command the result was blank. Now what should I go with?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss                              
   Here's the code - echo " So what is the process id that is blocking tcp.."

set /p prcs_id="Enter the process id of the process you want to terminate :"

pause

echo I got the process id: %prcs_id%

pause 

taskkill /PID %prcs_id% /F

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Coud you please revert back the downvote Here's the code for checking -                                                             
echo " So what is the process id that is blocking tcp.."

set /p prcs_id="Enter the process id of the process you want to terminate :"

pause

echo I got the process id: %prcs_id%

pause 

taskkill /PID %prcs_id% /F

Comment: I didn't downvote you...

Comment: Posting code in comments is ***not*** acceptable.  Edit your question to remove the pictures, and add actual code in the question.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I am sorry then

Comment: @abelenky I know that's not acceptable but I uploaded them for better reference... May be someone is caught with the error I am facing right now..so!

Comment: I fixed it for you.  Do not ever post images like that again.  Do not post code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a line in your file

```
set /P prcs_id="Enter a process id : "
echo I got process ID: %prcs_id%
taskkill /PID %prcs_id% /F
```

See if the `prcs_id` is ***exactly*** what you think you entered.

I suspect that for some reason, it is not quite what you think you typed in?

---

I'm not entirely sure, but this may be the delayed-expansion problem.
Near the top of your batch file, add:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Then, change your taskkill line to be:

```
taskkill /PID !prcs_id! /F
```

(use `!` instead of `%`)

Comment: I am getting the prcs_id as blank. When I tried on using your code. Now what might be the error..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
@ECHO OFF
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit)
SET /P MyPID=Please enter your PID:
IF "%MyPID%"=="" GOTO Error
ECHO This %MyPID% PID will terminated
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter PID
:End
pause
taskkill /PID %MyPID% /t
```